# How do I run a filter on a getNearest() query in RethinkDB?

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, thinky

I have a table with users and their locations saved as `r.point` datatypes & a `geo` index set on them. I am trying to run a `.getNearest()` query, which returns all the users closest to the given user (say, *Mr. X*). The results return all the users closest to *Mr. X*, but also include *Mr. X*. How do I filter all users **except** *Mr. X*?

**What I've tried so far —**

1. In RethinkDB's Data Explorer (Plain ReQL commands)

   ```
   r.db('myDb').table('myTable').getNearest(r.point(-20, 39), {index: 'location'}).filter(function(user) {return user.id !== '2ff8902e-97f0-431a-a51c-900a57532967'}); // Assuming Mr.X's `id` is `2ff8902e-97f0-431a-a51c-900a57532967`
   ```

   This returns all users, including *Mr. X*. Attempt #2 was -

   ```
   r.db('myDb').table('myTable').getNearest(r.point(-20, 39), {index: 'location', maxDist:9000000}).filter(r.row('id').ne('2ff8902e-97f0-431a-a51c-900a57532967'));
   ```

   This returns nothing.
2. In [thinky](https://thinky.io/documentation/), a Node.js ORM for RethinkDB.

   ```
   UserModel.getNearest(r.point(-20, 39), {index: 'location'}).filter(function(user) {return user.id !== '2ff8902e-97f0-431a-a51c-900a57532967'}).run();
   ```

   This returns all users, including *Mr. X*.

**One solution I'm already aware of —**

Using Thinky, I can do this.

```
const userId = '2ff8902e-97f0-431a-a51c-900a57532967';
const location = r.point(-20, 39);
const queryOptions = {index: 'location'};
UserModel.getNearest(location, queryOptions).run().then(function (users) {
  return users.filter(function(user) {
    return user.doc.id !== userId;
  });
});
```

I have a feeling I can make this faster; by making sure either the `.filter()` or another alternative function is run on the RethinkDB server than on my end. Is there room for improvement here? Or perhaps a nicer solution that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do it correct and almost there. You just happen to use `filter` with wrong key.

```
r.db('myDb').table('myTable').getNearest(r.point(-20, 39), {index: 'location'})
    .filter(function(user) {
           return user('doc')('id').ne('2ff8902e-97f0-431a-a51c-900a57532967')
    })
```

The key thin is:

1. `getNearest` returns an array of document. Each document has two fields: `dist` and `doc`(which is the document in table itself). Hence here we are using `user('doc')('id')` to get the key.  https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get_nearest/
2. Inside `filter` function, we have to use ReQL command, in this case, the `ne` mean, not equal. https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/ne/

This is fast because we have the index on location. And `filter` function is executed on RethinkDB server.

Comment: Thanks! I was very close to this solution myself. For anyone looking to implement this in Thinky, here's how I did it — https://gist.github.com/paambaati/591f062838204feacaf4